# pushing to hashmap of lists

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a structure like so:

```
{
    id1: [item1, item2, item3],
    id2: [item2, item3, item4]
}
```

to keep track of the items each ID has.

I know I could achieve this with a hashmap of the form: `HashMap<ID, ArrayList<Items>>`

But then I'd constantly be pre-emptively checking for the existence of the `ID: ArrayList<Items>`, and instantiating a new empty array list when one doesn't exist for an ID, before pushing the Item.

Is there a more specialised Class I can use to accomplish this form of structure, or is this checking un-aviodable.

I want something like:

```
entries = new SomeMapListClass<ID, Item>();
entries.put(ID, ...Items); // handles array internally
Items[] = entries.get(ID);
```

I don't know the ID's before hand so I can't initially fill the HashMap with empty arrays.

Comment: the problem with checking for duplicates... while it should be pretty simple to wrap whatever class, and let it add the nested elements by itself.

Answer (score 3):

> But then I'd constantly be pre-emptively checking for the existence of the ID: ArrayList, and instantiating a new empty array list when one doesn't exist for an ID, before pushing the Item.

This is perfectly acceptable, and the `Map` interface provides methods to help you with this. For example:

```
Map<ID, List<Items>> map = new HashMap<>();

map.computeIfAbsent(id, $ -> new ArrayList<>()).add(item);
```

It's as simple as this because [`Map#computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) returns the mapped value (if it exists), or the computed value if it doesn't.

So to answer your question, a `Map<ID, List<Items>>` is perfectly fine to use in this case.

Comment: so computeifabsent is essentially a way to ensure a base/default value exists at a key?

Comment: Yes, it can be used to achieve that. If the `id` key doesn't exist in my example, then a `new ArrayList<>()` will be inserted as the value for that key, and then the same `List` is returned so you can immediately add an element to it.

Comment: I think it would be exactly what I was looking for if it was like this instead: `Map<ID, List<Items>> map = new HashMap<>().computeIfAbsent(() -> new ArrayList<>());` and automatically ran the absent callback when trying to get a *any* key in the future

Comment: Unfortunately, what you're looking for does not exist in the Java API. If you're open to using external libraries, check out Guava's [Multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) data type.

Comment: Yes, the MultiMap is PERFECT, but it'd probably be too expensive to include guava for.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that complicated to implement your own HashMapList :

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

public class HashMapList<T, E> {

private HashMap<T, ArrayList<E>> map = new HashMap<T, ArrayList<E>>();

/* Insert item into list at key */
public void put(T key, E item) {
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key,  new ArrayList<E>());
    }
    map.get(key).add(item);
}

/* Insert list of items at key */
public void put(T key, ArrayList<E> items) {
    map.put(key, items);
}

/* Get list of items at key */
public ArrayList<E> get(T key){
    return map.get(key);
}

/* Check if hashMapList contains key */
public boolean containsKey(T key) {
    return map.containsKey(key);
}

/* Check if list at key contains value . */
public boolean containsKeyValue(T key, E value) {
    ArrayList<E> list = get(key);
    if (list == null) return false;
    return list.contains(value);
}

/* Get list of key */
public Set<T> keySet(){
    return map.keySet();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return map.toString();
}

}
```

Comment: I know, but I was looking for already tried-and-tested solutions. Such as Guava's `MultiMap`

Comment: This is also tried and tested. We are not writing a new data structure it is just a wrapper around existing classes.

Comment: Tried, Tested and *Optimised*. This is a naive approach. You could create an arraylist class every time you want to make use a list, because `It's not that complicated to implement your own`.